# What are the differences "under the hood" between running from jruby and a warbled jar?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, warbler

I am having a problem where a libgdx program runs fine when run from the command line with `jruby <filename>.rb` but when I warble it into a jar and run `java -jar <filename>.jar` it runs and then closes without displaying a window.

Since I'm no expert on java or jruby I'd like to know what goes on under the hood, so to speak, in an attempt to solve this problem I'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the libgdx library inside the jar, try this, execute the jar with:

```
java -cp gdx.jar -jar <filename>.jar
```

Assuming that the libgdx.jar is in the same folder. It's simply a classpath problem probably

Comment: No it's in the jar. I checked :( I just wen't back to haxe for game programming. Thanks though!